# Cannot read property 'EIP712Domain' of undefined

Tags: metamask

I get this when trying to recover the address using `eth-sig-util` as described [here](https://medium.com/metamask/scaling-web3-with-signtypeddata-91d6efc8b290). The code is very simple and this is all it contains:

```
var sigUtil = require('eth-sig-util')

var recovered = sigUtil.recoverTypedSignature({
  data: JSON.parse('[{"type":"string","name":"Order Type","value":"sell"},{"type":"string","name":"Token Symbol","value":"FDR"},{"type":"string","name":"Amount","value":"10"},{"type":"string","name":"Rate","value":"0.001"},{"type":"string","name":"Expires In","value":"2"}]'),
  sig: '0xdeletedsomechars1944340987bb77f08d1383f791f097f4f6ddceead4dc77f28bac053c0cbd6465dc3844de12aea36f9d8e67db6f80f92ef0f4027ee6f08ef6feefe63a1c'
})
```

Comment: OK, just downgraded eth-sig-util from 2.0.1=>1.4.2 and it works....

Comment: I get the same result.  Works in 1.4.2, does not work in 2.0.2